# vuex-persistedstate not saving class methods

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'd like to preference this by saying my backgrounds in in C# so I like declaring methods within my classes.  I've created a user class that contains properties and methods and I've added this to my vuex-persistedstate.  One of the methods is a logout() method which clears out the properties.  When I tried to invoke this method I got the following error:

```
TypeError: this.$data.user.logout is not a function
```

I then reviewed local storage and noted the user did not have reference to the class method.  So I went ahead and copied the logic from the method into my vue component and it worked so I'm assuming the issue is vuex-persistedstate does not save references to methods which is why the method call did not work.

I'd like to declare the logout method in one location rather than spreading it out across vue components, what is the best practice for accomplishing this?  Is it possible to do this in the class declaration or do I need a user helper file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure Berco!  My code is also up on GitHub so you can review it there too, but basically it seems to me that vuex does not store methods.  The first file you should review is my user.js file:

https://github.com/Joseph-Anthony-King/SudokuCollective/blob/master/SudokuCollective.WebApi/client/src/models/user.js

In this file I have a method called shallow clone which takes the info received from the API and assigns it to the user:

```
shallowClone(data) {

    if (data !== undefined) {

        this.id = data.id;
        this.userName = data.userName;
        this.firstName = data.firstName;
        this.lastName = data.lastName;
        this.nickName = data.nickName;
        this.fullName = data.fullName;
        this.email = data.email;
        this.isActive = data.isActive;
        this.isAdmin = data.isAdmin
        this.isSuperUser = data.isSuperUser;
        this.dateCreated = data.dateCreated;
        this.dateUpdated = data.dateUpdated;
        this.isLoggedIn = data.isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

You of course don't need to abstract this away but I've found it makes the code easier to maintain.

Then in the mounted() lifecycle hook I assign the user received from the API to the component user via the shallowClone method.  Please bear in mind I've done additional work on this project and the login form is now it's own component which receives the user as a prop from the app:

https://github.com/Joseph-Anthony-King/SudokuCollective/blob/master/SudokuCollective.WebApi/client/src/components/LoginForm.vue

```
mounted() {
let self = this;
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    self.authenticate();
  }
});
this.$data.user = new User();
this.$data.user.shallowClone(this.$props.userForAuthentication);
},
```

The full code can be reviewed here:

https://github.com/Joseph-Anthony-King/SudokuCollective

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... I'm working on improving it.  Basically I use the values pulled from localstorage into vuex to create a new user object in the vue component that has reference to the methods located in my user class declaration.  I recalled recommendations that we should create clones of objects pulled from vuex for use within the vue component.  I'm still refining the code but that's basic idea.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Does your solution work? Care to share?

Comment: Hi Berco Beute, I've added a new answer detailing my solution.  Please let me know if you have any questions.